# Squid Proxy use for specific websites

Tags: proxy, squid, whitelist

So i have squid proxy server installed and running on my ec2 instance. my task is to have any pc client connected to the proxy only the proxy when accessing certain sites and will use regular wifi connection for everything else. Something like a whitelist, or only use the proxy for certain specific sites and nothing else.

Is such a thing achievable by any chance?

any help or guidance is greatly appreciated.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

To force the use of proxy for specific domain you can use acl and never_direct in your configuration
Example:-

```
acl vkdomain dstdomain xyz.com
never_direct allow vkdomain
```

The above configuration will always proxy xyz.com.

For Whitelist, you can use acl where you can create a file and insert all the domains which you need to proxy.

Example - For proxying all the domains and subdomains for example.com, xyz.com. Create a file whitelist.txt and insert the below text

```
.example.com
.xyz.com
```

Now in you squid configuration use the below acl for whitelist

```
acl whitelist dstdomain "/path/to/whitelist.txt"
```

The above configuration will proxy all the domains and subdomains of example.com and xyz.com

Answer (score 0):

If the squid is only for internet, you may take a look at pac(proxy auto configuration).

Create a pac file xxx.pac like such below, and deploy it at some simple web server.

```
function FindProxyForURL(url, host) {
    // use proxy for specific domains
    if (shExpMatch(host, "whitelist.com")) {
        return "PROXY squidip:port";
    }
    // by default use no proxy
    return "DIRECT";
}
```

Then set the pac url http://simple-web-server/xxx.pac at 
Internet Options -> Connections -> Lan Settings -> Use automatic configuration script